# Merge dataframes with many rownames == NA's in R

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge the following data, data1 and data2.

```
> data1 
      A       B   C     D    E   F  
alpha "Jenna" "1" "50"  "60" "7" "1"
<NA>  NA      NA  "67"  "99" NA  NA 
<NA>  NA      NA  "55"  NA   NA  NA 
<NA>  NA      NA  "45"  NA   NA  NA 
beta  "Jenna" "1" "333" "89" "8" "1"
<NA>  NA      NA  "755" "74" NA  NA 
<NA>  NA      NA  "433" NA   NA  NA 
<NA>  NA      NA  "300" NA   NA  NA 

> data2
      A      B   C     D     E    F  
alpha "Lena" "1" "23"  "77"  "7"  "1"
<NA>  NA     NA  "67"  "103" NA   NA 
<NA>  NA     NA  "55"  NA    NA   NA  # note here only have 2 rows but 3 above
deta  "Lena" "1" "599" "9"   "76" "1" #note this one is deta not beta 
<NA>  NA     NA  "763" "88"  NA   NA 
<NA>  NA     NA  "1"   NA    NA   NA 
<NA>  NA     NA  "3"   NA    NA   NA
```

into this:
[image]

Basically, merge the df according to the rownames. If not exist, fill with NA.
*I don't want to add in the extra rownames (i.e. deta) manually. I've got some idea like finding the larger nrow(df), then ... etc ??

```
> dput(data1)
structure(c("Jenna", NA, NA, NA, "Jenna", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, "50", "67", "55", "45", "333", "755", 
"433", "300", "60", "99", NA, NA, "89", "74", NA, NA, "7", NA, 
NA, NA, "8", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("alpha", NA, NA, NA, "beta", NA, NA, 
NA), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))
> dput(data2)
structure(c("Lena", NA, NA, "Lena", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, 
"1", NA, NA, NA, "23", "67", "55", "599", "763", "1", "3", "77", 
"103", NA, "9", "88", NA, NA, "7", NA, NA, "76", NA, NA, NA, 
"1", NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 7:6, .Dimnames = list(c("alpha", 
NA, NA, "deta", NA, NA, NA), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))
```

Comment: Do you need `merge(data1, data2, by = 'row.names', all = TRUE)`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to expand the rows based on the occurrence of `NA` before doing the `merge`.  Create a numeric index based on the non-NA elements (or use `na.locf0` from `zoo`), `split` the sequence of rows of data (or get the `table` of 'v1', 'v2' and take the `max` of the frequency), expand the rows by padding NA rows based on the 'l1' and then do a `merge` on the row.names after filling the rownames with the non-NA element (`na.locf0`), change the row names of the output by `replace`ing some of the elements to NA

```
library(zoo)
v1 <- cumsum(!is.na(row.names(data1)))
v2 <- cumsum(!is.na(row.names(data2)))

lst1 <- split(seq_len(nrow(data1)), v1)
lst2 <- split(seq_len(nrow(data2)), v2)

l1 <- pmax(lengths(lst1), lengths(lst2))

dat1n <- do.call(rbind,  Map(function(x, y) data1[`length<-`(x, y), ], lst1, l1))
dat2n <- do.call(rbind,  Map(function(x, y) data2[`length<-`(x, y), ], lst2, l1))
row.names(dat1n) <- na.locf0(row.names(dat1n))
row.names(dat2n) <- na.locf0(row.names(dat2n))
out <-  merge(dat1n, dat2n, by = 'row.names', all = TRUE)

out1 <- as.matrix(out[-1])
row.names(out1) <- replace(out[,1], grepl("\\.\\d+$", out[,1]), NA)


out1
#      A.x     B.x C.x   D.x  E.x F.x A.y    B.y C.y   D.y   E.y  F.y
#alpha "Jenna" "1" "50"  "60" "7" "1" "Lena" "1" "23"  "77"  "7"  "1"
#<NA>  NA      NA  "67"  "99" NA  NA  NA     NA  "67"  "103" NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  "55"  NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  "55"  NA    NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  "45"  NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   NA 
#beta  "Jenna" "1" "333" "89" "8" "1" NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  "755" "74" NA  NA  NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  "433" NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  "300" NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   NA 
#deta  NA      NA  NA    NA   NA  NA  "Lena" "1" "599" "9"   "76" "1"
#<NA>  NA      NA  NA    NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  "763" "88"  NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  NA    NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  "1"   NA    NA   NA 
#<NA>  NA      NA  NA    NA   NA  NA  NA     NA  "3"   NA    NA   NA
```

Comment: Great answers! But when I apply to my data (there are more than 10 dfs like these given examples), some of the rownames got the letter `"X"` at the front. For exmaple, `"ABC"` becomes `"XABC"`. Also, some of the rownames do not translate the correct symbol. For example, `"beta-[>0]"` becomes `"beta...0."`. Rownames are not sorted either :(

Comment: @JohnnyTon `merge` returns a data.frame and data.frame doesn't support duplicate column names or row names.  That is the reason I changed in the last step to `as.matrix`

Comment: Oh! that's where the `X` comes from. I think I know how to fix it. Thanks! However, how can I sort the data by rownames? because they have to be sort as a chunk (like alpha as a chunk, beta as another chunk... etc)

Comment: @JohnnyTon I would use the 'Row.names' column in 'out' to order i.e. `out1[order(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", out$Row.names)),]`